# What happens to electrons on accelerated charged plate?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

If I charge an aluminum circular plate with 10 000 V and rotate it will the electrons stay in place or rotate with plate?

Will it behave the same if instead of one single plate I have a pattern of aluminum rays from center to edges seprated with some rays of plastic?

I presume that if I spin the plate in static magnetic field with lines parallel to axis of spin then in first case the force pushing the electrons outside (or inside) will stop the electrons from spinning, in the second they will gather on the edge of the aluminum "rays" and some will run away to the air, some will be successfully pushed out to the edge of circular plate.

Is that what will happen?

Comment: I don't think you will get any electrons to fly off of your plates just by spinning them.

Comment: Charging it to a particular voltage doesn't really affect the behavior.  Even an uncharged plate still has movable electrons.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395007/voltage-and-rotating-wire

Comment: @BowlOfRed  Well the faraday disk, with rotating magnet of same size as the disk, or any neodymium magnet spinned pushes electrons out which would be strange if they were free and could move independently from protons in that material.

Comment: Any individual "free electron" in the metal is free to move independently.  But the bulk movement is constrained by the electric fields that will be created by their movement.  The final position will be one where all the forces sum to zero (inertial and electromagnetic).  It's just that in most situations the inertial forces are so small they can be ignored.

Comment: @BowlOfRed But what will happen exactly? Will they be free enough to move inside meterial easy enough that when the material is spinned they will rather stay in place in relation to external frame of reference  or will spin with the material? Is their rediness to spin with the material proportional to the resistance of material in the direction of circular path arround the axis of rotation? This would imply that to make them spin one should create a plate in shape of rays separated with insulator, correct?

Comment: Resistance means that they will tend to stay with the bulk material.  Otherwise there would be a current that is dissipating energy.